# PHP - Data Analysis System

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I'm currently working on a project and need some advice on the best way to handle this project.

I have a client that requires a data analysis system to be built. The problem is that the data is sitting on multiple databases, in multiple tables with a wide range of different fields. for example:

```
database 1 > table 1 > field(name) > field(cell)
database 1 > table 2 > field(region) > field(cell)
database 2 > table 1 > field(cell) > field(age)
```

so now basically each database for example is a different website and they want to be able to see how many users that visit db 1 also visit db 2. They also want to be able to search a unique identifier in most cases will be the users cellphone number and have all the details that they user has entered across all db's

All together there is about 100 fields across 10 tables across 3 or 4 databases.

So I'm a bit stuck on the best way to handle this and to make sure the system can be easily modified/upgraded to include new db's, new tables and new fields as time goes on.

The options I have come up with so far,

1. is to create the system and just hard code each db, table, field and to just update those as time goes on or
2. Is to create some kind of script that will get all the data across all db and insert update one large database.

with option 2 would it be possible for the php script to see what fields are in the tables and create those fields in a new table?

I would really appreciate if anyone could give input as to the best way to handle this.

Comment: I'm afraid the goal of stackoverflow is not to resolve such problems. It is more like "I wanted to do this, I tried that and I got this error, what did i wrong?" http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.

Comment: I have a programming question and I asked, don't see what the issue is.

Comment: No, this is not a programming question, this is an extremely broad **design** question. Programming only comes after the design. "Best way" is also a very broad term, it may mean different things to different people.

Comment: If anyone is not happy with my question please feel free to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

with hardcoded databases, you have less work to merge all of data into one database. It will be slower with multi databases, but you can cache it.

Other way is to get all data and put it in one database. This requires knowing all design of database and then design it for your self for new design.

And depends if database is on one machine or multi machines with different databases. if this is the case less work, but not fast in respond is get data from multi database and let codeigniter handle all of data how you want to be displayed.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your insight.